# Fully Associative cache offset bits

Tags: caching

When dealing with a fully associative cache, why is it necessary to use an offset (or word),  if the entire cache is being searched anyway what will the offset do for you?

Answer (score 1):

Offset bits will allow more addresses to share the same block , when you increase the block size 
it will store more words  by removing offset bits